# video js quality selection with hls option

Tags: javascript

I want a quality selector for my video player plus auto option which will be selected at the first play, none of the video js plugind helped till now, any body can help me or interduce a good plugin for that implementation?

Comment: Could you provide more information on the used technologies, plugins and the current implementation?

Comment: @jACK like this one https://github.com/chrisboustead/videojs-hls-quality-selector , the first picture in gihub page is not showing after i follow instruction